# How can I call codebehind from an aspx page <asp:menuitem

Tags: asp.net

I need to have something similar to onclick for a `<asp:menuitem`, is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Could you clarify your question?

Comment: Yes, this is a very confusion question. Please clarify.

Comment: please provide more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can catch the Menu's [MenuItemClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.menu.menuitemclick.aspx)-Event. It has a [System.Web.UI.WebControls.MenuEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0sh04zxh.aspx) Parameter where you can get a reference to the Clicked MenuItem with its Item Property.